# Cannot access shared schema from other schema.graphql file in another schema.graphql file in schema stiching

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-tools

I have user schema in a userSchema.graphql file;

```
  id: String!
  userName: String!
  email: String!
  password: String!
}
```

and I have different schema.graphql file for login and register

and I cannot access User schema in the login/register schema

```
type Query{
    hi: String!
}
type Mutation {
    register( userName: String!, email: String!, password: String! ): User
}
```

I am using schema stiching from graphql tools 
and merging typeDefs and resolver from merge-graphql-schema package

```
import "graphql-import-node";
import { GraphQLSchema } from "graphql";
import { mergeResolvers, mergeTypes } from "merge-graphql-schemas";
import * as userSchema from './modules/auth/shared/schema.graphql'
import * as registerTypedefs from "./modules/auth/register/schema.graphql";
import registerResolver from "./modules/auth/register/registerResolver";

import * as todoTypedefs from "./modules/todo/schema.graphql";
import todoResolver from "./modules/todo/todoResolver";

import { makeExecutableSchema } from "graphql-tools";

const schema: GraphQLSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: mergeTypes([userSchema, registerTypedefs, todoTypedefs], { all: true }),
  resolvers: mergeResolvers([registerResolver, todoResolver])
});
export default schema;
```

I am getting the error

```
Error: Field register: Couldn't find type User in any of the schemas.
    at collectNode (E:\graphql\express-apollo-server\node_modules\graphql-import\src\definition.ts:154:15)
    at E:\graphql\express-apollo-server\node_modules\graphql-import\src\definition.ts:135:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

**EDIT**
I have used fileLoader from 'merge-graphql-schemas'
and it worked perfectly

```
import { mergeResolvers, mergeTypes, fileLoader } from "merge-graphql-schemas";


const typesArray = fileLoader(path.join(__dirname, './modules/**/*.graphql'), { recursive: true })
```

```
const schema: GraphQLSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: mergeTypes(typesArray, { all: true }),
  resolvers: mergeResolvers([registerResolver, loginRegister, todoResolver, storyResolver])
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a require-graphql-file along with lodash merge in my project and same scenario works for me.

```
import requireGraphQLFile from 'require-graphql-file';
import { merge } from 'lodash';

const $userSchema = requireGraphQLFile('./schema/yourFolder/userSchema.graphql');
const $registerTypedefs= requireGraphQLFile('./schema/yourFolder/register.graphql');

import registerResolver from "./modules/auth/register/registerResolver";
import todoResolver from "./modules/todo/todoResolver";

const schema: GraphQLSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
   typeDefs: [$userSchema, 
              $registerTypedefs,
              todoTypedefs
             ],              
   resolvers: merge(registerResolver, todoResolver)
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I am using typescript, and its @types is not present. so it is not working.